# Can document.createElement be combined

Tags: javascript

Can multiple elements be created without rewriting `document.createElement()` each time..

```
document.createElement("article");
document.createElement("footer");
document.createElement("header");
document.createElement("hgroup");
document.createElement("nav");
```

---

These would be great..

```
document.createElements("article,footer,header,hgroup,nav");
```

or

```
var elems = ["article","footer","header","hgroup","nav"];
document.createElement(elems);
```

Comment: Not really, you could perhaps pass an array of element-types to a function that returns an array/object of elements, though? Or use `element.innerHTML` to write HTML directly. But without context, we can't really offer anything other than "no."

Comment: Yes, for example using a function with a shorter name, if all you're concerned about is having to type so much. Maybe provide more context including a code excerpt for more detailed suggestions.

Comment: Note that creating all those elements and just storing them in an array is not going to help you at all when you actually want to do anything with them, such as place them in the document or add content to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an array of element tag names you want:

```
var names = ["article", "footer", "header", "hgroup", "nav"];
```

Then use the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to create an array of created elements:

```
var elements = names.map(document.createElement, document);
```

However, you should keep in mind that internally this still calls the `createElement` function over and over using a loop. It just looks a bit nicer in your code.

EDIT:
You need to specify the `this` argument as `document` so `createElement` can be called in the correct context.

Answer (score 4):

You could create your own method:

```js
function createElements( arr ) {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    arr.forEach(function creator ( tagname ) {
        fragment.appendChild( document.createElement( tagname ) );
    });
    return fragment;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```js
createElements( [ "p", "div", "footer" ] );
```

This returns a `documentFragment`, which you could then append as a child anywhere in your DOM.

I don't know *why* you would want to do this though :)